# What is a universal quantum algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Nobody seems to define the term anywhere.  It's in the abstract of ["Factoring integers with sublinear resources on a superconducting quantum processor"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.12372) by Bao Yan, Ziqi Tan, Shijie Wei et alia, 2022.

> Shor's algorithm has seriously challenged information security based on public key cryptosystems. However, to break the widely used RSA-2048 scheme, one needs millions of physical qubits, which is far beyond current technical capabilities. Here, we report a **universal quantum algorithm** for integer factorization by combining the classical lattice reduction with a quantum approximate optimization algorithm (QAOA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Nobody seems to define the term anywhere."

The term "universal quantum algorithm" is not commonly used. In the case of factoring numbers it could mean one of two things:

1. Some algorithms for factoring numbers do not exploit "universal quantum computers" meaning that they could work on simpler quantum annealers like the D-Wave machine which cannot do universal quantum computation. These would not be "universal" quantum algorithms, and ones that ***do*** require universal quantum computers could (although it wouldn't be a very common way to say it) be called "universal".
2. Some algorithms for factoring numbers cater only to specific types of numbers (e.g. semiprime numbers, or numbers of the form $(p-1)(q-1)$ for primes $p$ and $q$). These include:

- Trial division
- Wheel factorization
- Pollard's rho algorithm
- Algebraic-group factorization algorithms
- Fermat's factorization method
- Euler's factorization method
- Special number field sieve

In the paper that you mentioned, the algorithm can run on a non-universal D-Wave machine (even though they used QAOA on a circuit-based machine to solve the QUBO part of their algorithm, instead of just running it on a D-Wave machine), they more likely to mean the second option above. **They mean that their algorithm will work for the factorization of any integer.**

I recently wrote a much longer explanation of that paper here, in the answer to [Quantum Computing Used to Break RSA by "fixing" Schnorr's Recent Factorization Claim?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/103953/59140).

Answer (score 2):

I am not very sure, but it's not a technical term. It just means an algorithm that works in every case, more like a generalised algorithm.
So what I think that means is that This algorithm will surely factor every integer.